Get JS Figlet function to return text instead of applying it to an element
I am using the Figlet script from https://github.com/scottgonzalez/figlet-js
It's the highly simplified version of the original.
The way to use it, is to apply it to an element, like $("#example").figlet("text", "drpepper"); where drpepper is one of the fonts.
This is done by:
$.fn.figlet = function(text, font) {
    var elems = this;
    Figlet.write(text, font || $.fn.figlet.defaultFont, function(str) {
        elems.text(str);
    });
    return this;
};

How can I change that function to simply return text and use it like var test = figlet("text","drpepper");?
I want the Figlet value in a variable, so I can do other stuff with it.
Trying it like figlet(a,b) gets me a 'figlet is not defined'.
I have tried the code below, but without success:
function figlet(text, font) {
    Figlet.write(text, font || $.fn.figlet.defaultFont, function(str) {
        return str;
    });
};


The issue with this cut-down version of figlet is that it uses an async method to load the required font.   They may be a way to use an existing font.  Looking at the jquery.figlet.js, there's Figlet.loadFont which makes an ajax call.  It also uses callback pattern rather than promise.

This answer should help: how do I return the value of an aysnc call - scroll down to the callback section
